# Writing my own Q&A while expecting other answers

Tags: discussion, answers

I have had a couple of questions in the past where I said something like

> I am having a problem with [blank]. I think I should probably do [second blank].

I usually write the second sentence with uncertainty to encourage explanation. In a couple of cases "[second blank]" was the right answer. I *could* have taken that sentence and written a small answer.

As long as the question and answer are strong enough to stand on their own do you see any reason why I cannot answer my own question like this. I get that answering your own questions is encouraged. I more mean that I have a reservation about it being the best answer.

Comment: I like my fake internet points.

Answer (score 2):

Are others giving your answer as an answer below?  If you are really curious and want others answers, even if they happen to align with your's I find it's 'nicer' to let them have the up votes.  If no one has used your 'answer', there might be a reason for it.  If you go and do research on your question and get good answers, then by all means share what you learned!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. Thanks. It for things that could have more than one approach.... using a different tool that would not have occurred to me.

Answer (score 1):

Bowlturner pretty much covered it but I'll add some more thoughts since this is too long for a comment and, hey, this is meta.

It depends on how others responded to your question.

Self answer if...

1. nobody else answered your question
2. nobody else recommended your suggested solution (maybe some even recommended against it) but you found it to work well anyway

Besides that, there might be some situations in which someone mentioned it in passing but you think it requires more detail or you think everyone needs to know why it's such a great solution. In those cases, it might be worth posting a more detailed answer.